# Ubuntu Terminal Errors

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Whenever I open my terminal I get this error at the top:

```
bash: /etc/bash_completion.d/hping2: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `$( compgen -W '02 04 08 10' )'
bash: /etc/bash_completion.d/hping2: line 22: `            $COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '02 04 08 10' ) )'
```

Comment: Could you please post the `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`?

Comment: bashrc - http://pastebin.com/7kBFNTT9  profile http://pastebin.com/HaeHrpeX

Comment: and the snippet of `/etc/bash_completion.d/hping2` around the line 22?

Comment: full script - http://pastebin.com/6pBartwz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dollar sign at the begin of the line 22 and try again:

```
COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '02 04 08 10' ) )
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Do you have any idea what might have caused it?

Comment: It resides in /etc, which meant that unless it's been manually been modified, it may have been caused by an buggy update. Have you made an on your OS? In fact, what OS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by, ahem, a syntax error in one of the bash completion scripts (in this case it is the completion script for `hping2`). When the terminal starts a program called [`bash`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) to handle your terminal session, `bash` run its initialization scripts, including the completion script `/etc/bash_completion.d/hping2`.

For some reason, that script on your computer is messed up (maybe somebody accidentally edited it), resulting in the syntax error. I think the right way to fix it would be to change that line to

```
COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '02 04 08 10' ) )
```

(remove the `$` at the beginning of the line).